# Access ssh of multiple Linux systems(not single)

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi, ssh-tunnel

I have multiple raspberry pi setup up at various places. I want to gain ssh access to them from anywhere through internet.

One of the main solution I saw over internet was to use ssh forwarding.
I have a cloud system setup and I forward my ssh in my raspberry pi to my cloud system.

In that way I can access the remote raspberry pi at different locations through my cloud system.

My problem is:

1. What if I run out of ports in the cloud system after sometime.
2. What if I want to install the raspberry pi so that it connects to a port in the system automatically during installation.
3. I don't want to use VPN because it can become too heavy for a raspberry pi.

Is there any way I can access all my pi?

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions for you.

(1) Use VPN - VPN will not slow down you pi. VPN works at the router where the authentication & encryption will happen.  Typically you will see no slowdown issues with VPN.

(2) Use port forwarding but to only one server or even a pi.  Once you in one pi or server you can then ssh from that server/pi to other pis.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have some doubts with your solutions. (1) Is it possible to use only ssh over vpn or all the traffic coming and going to pi will go through vpn server?  (2) Considering all my pi are in different network how do I connect from one pi to another without VPN?

Comment: (1) VPN will only be active when you connect remotely. And it will only be active for your connection.  Everything else will proceed as usual.  (2) I did not realize that the pis are at various location.  In that case, yes, you will have to VPN to each location.  Or simply use port forwarding, but you will have to setup port forward at each site.